# Como refletir sobre operadores sobrecarregáveis em C#?

Tags: c#, reflexão

Meu problema é o seguinte: estou escrevendo um interpretador e preciso realizar operações dinâmicas entre vários tipos.

Para isso uso vínculos dinâmicos fornecidos pela *DLR* que consiste em um objeto estático encapsulado dentro de um meta-objeto-dinâmico.

Acontece que ao refletir sobre os membros públicos de um `Int32` (o mesmo se dá para outros descendentes de `ValueType`) os campos, as propriedade, métodos e construtores são obtidos com sucesso, porém os operadores aritméticos(`op_xxx`) e suas sobrecargas não aparecem como resultado da reflexão.

Já tentei a função `Type.GetMethods()` e o resultado é o mesmo.

Como faço para obter o `MemberInfo` ou `MethodInfo` para os operadores aritméticos e operadores sobrecarregados?

PS: Membros é um dicionário cujo as chaves são `string` e o valores são listas de `MemberInfo`'s.

```
// Nesse exemplo eu faço a reflexão sobre os membros públicos do tipo Int32 mas as operações não aparecem no dicionário.
 int valor = 123; // Um valor arbitrário, o tipo que é interessante.

 //Dicionário onde ficarão guardado os resultados da reflexão.
 Dictionary<string, List<MemberInfo>> membros = new Dictionary<string,List<MemberInfo>>(); 
    //Reflete os membros de value e preenche o dicionário members.
    public Refletir() 
    {
        //obtém o tipo Int32 para reflexão
        Type tipo = valor.GetType(); 

        //Itera sobre os membros do tipo em questão
        foreach (var membro in tipo.GetMembers())
        {
            //Verifica se o dicionário já contém uma chave
            //para o nome do membro.
            if (membros.ContainsKey(membro.Name))
            {
                //Se já existir a chave adiciona o membro ao
                //valor cujo é uma lista de MemberInfo's.
                membros[membro.Name].Add(membro);
            } else {
                // Se a chave não existir é criada uma lista de
                // MemberInfo's onde é adicionada o membro atual
                // então a lista é adicionada ao dicionário de membros
                List<MemberInfo> lista = new List<MemberInfo>();
                lista.Add(membro);
                membros.Add(membro.Name, lista );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como informado neste fórum:
[Invoking operators by reflection](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0f3d554e-d8b9-45aa-bcf5-f720a7990522/invoking-operators-by-reflection)

> Se você definir seus próprios operadores, você pode utilizá-los usando reflection(...).
>
> Entretanto, com os tipos primitivos (como Int32) isso não é possível, pois o compilador lida com os valores diretamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.